# Type Inheritance in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to implement type inheritance in oracle 10g

Hereis my code:

```
create type stud_detail as object
(stud_id number(5),
stud_name varchar(8));
/


create type stud_result under stud_detail as
(status(P/F)? char(1));
/
```

I get this error:

> ERROR at line 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AS" when expecting
>   one of the following:
>
> . ( not external JAVA_ BOUND_
>   1. create type stud_result under stud_detail as object
>   2. (status(P/F)? char(1));

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Declare your `stud_detail` type as `NOT FINAL`.  You can only inherit from a type that is `NOT FINAL`, and types are `FINAL` by default.
2. Lose the `AS` keyword in your `create type stud_result under stud_detail...` line.

Demonstration:

```
SQL> create type stud_detail as object (stud_id number(5), stud_name varchar2(8)) not final;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create type stud_result under stud_detail ("status(P/F)?" char(1));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> desc stud_result;
 stud_result extends LUKE.STUD_DETAIL
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STUD_ID                                            NUMBER(5)
 STUD_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(8)
 status(P/F)?                                       CHAR(1)
```

Note that I've changed `varchar` to `varchar2`, and put quotes around the name of the column `status(P/F)?`.

Comment: `varchar` is an alias for `varchar2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it is currently, but it might not be in the future.  See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1303 .

Comment: Oracle has been telling that for nearly 30 years now (I think the first time this sentence appeared in the 7.x manuals) - if they wanted to do that, they had plenty of opportunities. And if you create a table *today* it does not matter.